# Can't instantiate "scene object" [Unity Mirror Multiplayer]

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, scene, unity3d-mirror

I am trying to instantiate an object that already exists in the scene so that I can enlarge it and "zoom" in on it, but when I play the game and hover over an object, instead of showing the zoomed card, this error shows up:

```
Card1(Clone)(Clone) has already spawned. Don't call Instantiate for NetworkIdentities that were in the scene since the beginning (aka scene objects). Otherwise the client won't know which object to use for a SpawnSceneObject message.
```

NOTE: I am following a tutorial for a 2D Unity Card game with mirror (2019.2.15f1), and I am using a different version of Unity (2020.1.0f1).

**First, I am instantiating objects into my game with this script, which never throws any errors.**

```
[Command]
public void CmdDealCards()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        GameObject card = Instantiate(playerDeck[Random.Range(0, playerDeck.Count)], new Vector2(0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        NetworkServer.Spawn(card, connectionToClient);
        RpcShowCard(card, "Dealt");
    }
}
```

**The problem comes when I try to instantiate these objects again later, here:**

```
public void OnHoverEnter()
{
    zoomCard = Instantiate(gameObject, new Vector2(Input.mousePosition.x, 540), Quaternion.identity);
    zoomCard.transform.SetParent(Canvas.transform, true);
    zoomCard.layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Zoom");

    RectTransform rect = zoomCard.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
    rect.sizeDelta = new Vector2(240, 354);
}
```

Comment: Instead rather spawn a new **prefab** and implement the ability of "copying" the values and appearance from an existing card **network-wide** .. or simply have one prefab for each card and spawn the according prefab. The problem with `Instantiate` here is that it creates a deep clone of your existing object including its NetworkIdentity! I bet you understand what the problem is with two objects having the same NetworkIdentity in a networked app ;)

Comment: @derHugo thanks for the response! I’m following a tutorial where this code functions perfectly, so I thought it had to be possible, but it is an older version of Unity. So if I understand you correctly, I could (1) make a second prefab for each card (Card1Zoom for Card1, Card2Zoom for Card2, etc...) and then spawn those individually, or I could (2) make a new prefab (i.e. CardZoom) and spawn it whenever I need a zoomed card, and then copy the values of that card into it. I just need it to show up for the active client and not the other player. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really late answer, but I came across it while running into the same issue, and maybe in the future, someone will do the same as me, so:

What you've done is attached the wrong prefab to your CardZoom script in the Inspector.
[Image of Inspector with Zoom Card attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZFXV.png)

What I did, and presumably you also, was to attach Card1 here, which is where it was failing to duplicate the NetworkIdentity

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate this error.

If I change the name of an object after duplicating it, the objects that are now in existence as a result of being duplicated are now giving this error.

I deleted all objects that existed as a result of being duplicated and then named the source object the desired name in the hierarchy. There I am able to proceed in duplication with the desired name without the errors. I believe it has something to do with the deep cloning of the prefab in combination with network identities. I may have to look into this deeper later.